# How to realise nesting in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model, nested

I am trying to write correct mongodb model. There is a task:

You are designing a web application that manages organizational structure for parent and child companies.
Each company has two properties, they are company name and estimated annual earnings.
There are two types of companies:

```
1- Main company, 
2 - Subsidiary company.
```

The company can belong only to one company but can have a few child companies.

The application should allow a user to view/add/edit/delete any company.
- Company name and estimated earnings should be stored in database
- Show companies tree

**Example**:

```
Name | Company Estimated Earnings | Company Estimated Earnings + Child Companies Estimated Earnings
 -Company1 | 25K$ | 53K$
  --Company2 | 13K$ | 18K$
   ---Company3 | 5K$
  --Company4 | 10K$
- Nesting level is not limited
```

What is the best solution to realise data-model? (I am using Mongoose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can do something like this

```
companySchema =  {
    companyName: String,
    estimatedAnnualEarnings: Number,
    companyChildren: {mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref="Company"},
    companyType: {type: String,enum: ['Main', 'Subsidiary'] |
};
```